# Why an I getting this error reading an HTML table with the XML package in R?

Tags: xml, r

Here's my code:

```
library(XML)
rm(list=ls())
url.montco <- "http://webapp.montcopa.org/sherreal/salelist.asp?saledate=10/26/2011"
tbl <-data.frame(readHTMLTable(url.montco))[, c(3,5,6,8,9)]
```

This code worked in the past (a few years age). But now when I go back to it, I get this error. What is the error telling me and more importantly, how do I fix it ?

> Error in data.frame(`NULL` = NULL, `NULL` = list(`Law Reporter
>   Suppl.#` = c(1L,  :arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 392

Comment: the `readHTMLTable()` line returns a list. You need to select the second element of the list to get the dataframe.

Comment: did this solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this deserves to be an answer because I don't know what columns you're looking for, but I think you simply need to select the 2nd element of the list that is returned by `readHTMLTable()`:

```
library(XML)

url.montco <- "http://webapp.montcopa.org/sherreal/salelist.asp?saledate=10/26/2011"
tbl <- readHTMLTable(url.montco)[[2]][, c(3,5,6,8,9)]
```